# Cant access rest api deployed on https://locahost:8443 from war deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, ssl-certificate

I have designed rest api using jersey.I have created a web application and created a war out of it on elipse.I have deployed that war on the tomcat server.When I am starting the server from eclipse and accessing the web service I am  able to do it.But after deploying the war on tomcat and starting the server from tomcat/bin and then trying to access the web service using the java client I am getting the following error

```
Error 404:https://localhost:8443/SecureHttpsProject/rest/download not found
```

Here is the code to access the web service

```
Client client = null;

                com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig config = new com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig(); // SSL configuration 
                config.getProperties().put(com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties(getHostnameVerifier(), getSSLContext())); 
                client = Client.create(config);



                    WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri(p.getProperty("https://localhost:8443/SecureHttpsProject/rest/download")).build());
            Form f = new Form();    
            f.add("installableName", instName.getText());    
            f.add("searchPath", srchPath.getText());    
            f.add("targetPath", trgtPath.getText());
        String res= service.post(String.class,f);
        System.out.println("Result "+res);
            result.setText(res+"                 ");
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to access web service deployed on tomcat using war on https ?

Comment: I hope you are deploying under webapps

Comment: try using only 443 instead of 8443

Comment: Yes i ve deployed it under webapps.The point is its accessible if I start server from eclipse.But same doesnt seems to work after exporting project as .war and depollying in tomcat/webapps

Comment: are you able to open tomcat homepage (index.html) at `https://localhost:8443/` in standalone deployment?

Comment: yes.Whenever i deploy war using the manager app option on https://localhost:8443 page only then accessing the web service is an issue.And my environment uses a proxy ip.Would that be an issue?If yes then how do i resolve it?